# Questions about login persistence and use of login data when using Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I wrote the code so that the login data is stored in state, printed as console.log under the name UserImpL, and the Google login information of the login data is displayed.(**displayName**, **photoUrl** this two data)

However, when you refresh, the login data remains, but the photo and name you created on the Login Header disappear

I wrote the code to expose the picture and name when the login data exists, but I don't know why it disappeared.

Is the code wrong?

**Photo1**
[image]

**Photo2(Refresh)**
[image]

**Login Header of Top**

```
export default function Login() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((data) => {
      setUserData(data.user);
      console.log(data);
    });
  };
  //

  const handleCart = () =>
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      user != null ? navigate("/carts") : alert("로그인 해주세요.");
    });
  const handleGoogleLogOut = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    signOut(auth);
    setUserData(null);
    navigate("/");
  };
  const handleNewProduct = () => {
    navigate("/products/new");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {userData ? (
        userData.email === "whiteforcoding@gmail.com" ? (
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <button onClick={handleNewProduct}>
              <BsPencilFill />
            </button>
            <img
              src={userData.photoURL}
              alt={userData.displayName}
              className="w-9 ml-4 mr-2 rounded-full"
            />
            <p className="mr-4">{`${userData && userData.displayName} 님`}</p>
            <button onClick={handleGoogleLogOut}>Logout</button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <button onClick={handleCart}>
              <GrShop />
            </button>
            <img
              src={userData.photoURL}
              alt={userData.displayName}
              className="w-9 ml-5 mr-2 rounded-full"
            />
            <p className="mr-4">{`${userData && userData.displayName} 님`}</p>
            <button onClick={handleGoogleLogOut}>Logout</button>
          </div>
        )
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleGoogleLogin}>Login</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**FirebaseConFig**

```
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);

setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, provider);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.errorCode;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
  });

export const db = getFirestore(app);

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user != null) {
    console.log(user);
    console.log("Logged In");
  } else {
    console.log(user);
    console.log("No user");
  }
});
```